# Can you remove the hero image on blog posts?

Tags: feature-request, blog

When I open any of the blog posts, I am presented with a huge image at the top which forces me to scroll to read the first sentence. Can you please delete the hero or make it smaller?

Here is an example - https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/11/09/why-channels/?cb=1

[image: Screenshot of blog header image taking up most of the window]

Comment: Not a bug. I agree though, even on my 1920*1080 screen, you see 0 of the actual content before scrolling, and you should at least see a couple of sentences.

Comment: Why does the header need to grow to make room for "Blog" when scrolled to top? there's so much space to the right of that that would eliminate the jumping and make more room below

Comment: Never knew that was called a [hero image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image).  It would be better smaller at least.

Comment: It is what AdBlockers are for. I have adblocked.

Comment: Probably some designer thinks this is good, I would love to see someone defend this design.

Comment: And then I scroll down and it's *still* got 128-ish pixels of banner stuck to the top of the page that won't go away when I scroll. Go away, banner!

Comment: According Wikipedia "it presents an overview of the site's most important content", which are atoms, obviously. Or stars. Or neural networks.

Comment: Tabloid papers use large (unrelated) images to be able to obscure the fact that they provide little text with even less content. Same principle here, I guess.

Comment: You have it easy, on my screen the hero image doesn't even start until over half way down the page: https://imgur.com/PaoxWAh. Not only that, but when I scroll it takes up **the whole page**: https://imgur.com/a/YCy67

Comment: It seems all blog posts are like this, then they look awesome on [this page](https://stackoverflow.blog/).

Comment: Look how [it's beautiful](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/11/13/cliffs-insanity-dramatic-shifts-technologies-stack-overflow/?cb=1).